# Unable to properly wait for async HTTP response (Flask)

Tags: python, http, flask, beautifulsoup, python-asyncio

I have a function that does some web scraping with Beautiful Soup and requests_http. When I run the function file by itself (not in the context of my app / server) it returns exactly what I'd expect, so I'm scraping and returning the right content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession, AsyncHTMLSession
import json

base_url = 'https://somewebsite.com'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
}


async def scrape_webpage():
    results = []
    try: 
        session = HTMLSession()
        response = session.get(base_url)
        response.html.render(timeout=15)
        html = response.html.html
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')

        # Do some web scraping to get specific content, add it to results...
        return results

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
```

In my routes file, I have an API endpoint that gets called by the client upon rendering (fetch call inside UseEffect hook - in a React component). Id like to call the scrape_webpage function and WAIT for the response, and then return the response to the client. My scraper function is a little slow - it first has to render the JS on the page in order to get the HTML content, but I'm sure there's still a way to wait for a slow async function.

Here's the routes file:

```
from scrape import scrape_webpage
import json
import time
import asyncio
import aiohttp

content = {}
async def scrape():
    b = await scrape_webpage();
    content['res'] = b

@app.route('/api/asyncscrape')
async def scrape_async():
    try:
        asyncio.run(scrape())
    finally:
        return {'content': content}
```

Every time I start up my servers (client and api) when the client makes the request I get this error:

`TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a coroutine`

Any ideas on how I can successfully wait for the web scraper and then return the json to my client?

Comment: Is `scrape_beer_bazaar` the same thing as `scrape`?

Comment: `scrape_webpage` doesn’t await anything. You should either define it as a regular function or switch to an asyncio-aware library like aiohttp.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question.

Comment: I changed a line in the `scrape_webpage` function `html = await response.html.html`, so now its awaiting. Still gets stuck.

Comment: You can’t await arbitrary things. Is the error message the same or has it changed?

Comment: I changed up the code a little bit, it's not giving me an error now, but it's returning an empty dictionary - meaning it's not waiting for the json.

Comment: It doesn’t even contain the `res` key? That sounds like you have an uncaught exception somewhere that’s been handled silently by your finally block.

Comment: Thing is, when I run the file by itself, it returns the scraped data exactly as I need it. When I run it as a function that's called by an API endpoint (as part of my Flask app), it just return the empty dict.

Comment: Since you’re using Flask and your code isn’t asynchronous, you’d be better off dropping any use of asyncio. That might not immediately solve your problem but it would remove one variable. You can also catch the exception being raised by `scrape` (or something it calls) and see what the problem is.